# Running executable jar from Servlet

Tags: servlets

Cannot resolve the problem for 2 days already. I have an executable jar, runs with double click. Simple JFrame form. I need to put it on a website, so clicking the link at website should execute my application (my jar).

So, working in NETBEANS, I've created a web application, used Glassfish server. I made a MyServlet.java, which just prints some lines:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<h2>gdfdddddddddddddd</h2>");          

      //  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar JavaApplication131.jar");         

    }
}
```

In index.html this servlet is pointed out:

```
<body>
    <h4>CLick33 <a href="MyServlet">MyServlet Page</a></h4>
</body>
```

So by clicking the link text appears. No problems with that.

Now I need somehow to also execute my jar. I tried inserting into servlet:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar JavaApplication131.jar");
```

No help. It seems like my jar should be somehow updated with servlet class or connected to separate jar/war, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Could someone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

You are completely misunderstanding the concept of Servlet and your executable JAR in your question. What you are trying to achieve with your code is to execute the JAR in the context of the Servlet container. The security manager of the servlet container might have restrictions on executing external tools and thus might not execute your external JAR.

What you are asking for is actually to execute the JAR on the users client correct? If this is the case just provide a download link to the JAR and instructions as of how to execute it.

Or even better look into the Java Network Launch Protocol which is specifically designed to launch desktop applications downloaded from web resources.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html

Answer (score 0):

I want users not to download my jar. I wish to store it on server and just open it with a link.

Maybe you can provide some examples?

Comment: you're mixing two completely different concepts of programming in Java. Matthias Steinbauer gave you a useful link.